# Query against two tables in separate databases on the same server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to query two tables in two different databases on the same `SQL Server`. On one table, I need to get all the rows (simple select) and on the other, a select but where the id matches a parameter in my stored proc.

I tried doing this but get the error

> The multi-part identifier could not be bound.

How can I go about this?

QUERY:

```
  SELECT QUALITY_CENTER, POSTCODE_ID, (SELECT   [QCID]   
  FROM [Website_Interactive].[dbo].[IIPCentre_UserObject]
  WHere LoginID = @loginID)
  FROM IIP_QC_LIST
```

Comment: My money would be on missing the schema part of the fully qualified object name, eg MyDB.dbo.MyTable.

Comment: Just to be clear, you haven't left anything out from the query you posted correct?  Because if you try to do an `ORDER BY` or something using QCID outside of the subquery you would get that error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sounds like you mistyped something.  You can query a table in another DB using the following method:

```
SELECT tn.ID, tn.NAME
FROM [Database Name].[Schema].[TableName] as tn
```

I purposely added a two word database name because you have to put square brackets around that for it to be recognized.  Your Schema will most likely be `dbo`.

If you show us your query and give us the DB names I can provide a more complete answer.

**UPDATE:**

Are you sure you are spelling "Center" correctly?  I noticed you spelled it "centre" in `IIPCentre_UserObject` which I think might be right for the UK (?) but you spelled it "center" for `QUALITY_CENTER`.  I would assume it's spelled one way or the other in your environment.

Comment: Is it posible to add user credentials to this query if the current user doenst have permission to this table?

Comment: The square brackets are important, even if the database name is a single word.  Without them you could get `Invalid object name` errors.

Answer (score 7):

You can easily do that by providing the FQN (Fully Qualified Name) to the SQL object (in this case your SQL table). The FQN syntax for a table is as such:

```
[database-name].[schema-name].[table-name]
```

Example:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM Database1.Schema1.Table1
UNION 
SELECT a, b, c FROM Database2.Schema2.Table2
```

Where Database1 is your first database and Database2 is your second.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible/straightforward to select from different databases on the same server. You need to use a fully qualified name i.e.

```
SELECT * from database.schema.table
```

For example

```
SELECT * FROM northwind.dbo.orders where id = @id
```

Comment: What is possible may still be prohibitively expensive. Is there an additional cost involved when joining two tables from different databases but still on the same database server? Does the database provide algorithms to do it more or less efficiently if different servers are involved (no network cost assumed)? The answer so far is a bit short for a 10k+ magician 8-(

Comment: @PatrickFromberg Sorry to disappoint, though the information you were hoping for is way outside the scope of the original question (before the post-answer edits). Yours is an excellent question and may deserve it's own post. Short answer, in MS SQL Server joining between two tables in different databases on the same server is largely equivalent to two tables in the same database. Linked server queries can be quite costly although SQL Server still attempts to optimize as best as possible but it inevitably requires sending potentially large amounts of data across the network to perform the join.

Answer (score 0):

You can query two separate database if the table from 1 database is the same value with another table

like these:

```
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.MyTable db1,DB2.dbo.MyTable db2 where db1.table1=db2.table1
```